# Password input length longer than 5 characters not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on this form, but I have an issue with the JavaScript code at line #36.
I'm trying to make password length longer than 5 characters, and it works very well as it shows up an alert which says password is too short if its not longer than 5. But the problem comes when password is longer than 5. I'd like it to be valid, delete the alert and gains the '.succeed' class so it can have the styles. I tried this code below but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const form = {
    name: '',
    secondName: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
}


const name1 = document.querySelector('#first-name');
const name2 = document.querySelector('#second-name');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');

name1.addEventListener('blur', validar);
name2.addEventListener('blur', validar);
email.addEventListener('blur', validar);
password.addEventListener('input', validar);

function validar(e){

    
    if(e.target.value.trim() === ''){
        alerta(`This field can't be empty`, e.target.parentElement);
        e.target.classList.add('failed');
        e.target.classList.remove('succeed');
        form[e.target.name] ='';
        return;
    }
    
    if(e.target.name === 'email' && !validarEmail(e.target.value.trim())){
        alerta(`Please enter a valid email`, e.target.parentElement);
        form[e.target.name] ='';
        return;
    }
    
    if(e.target.name === 'password' && !e.target.value.lenght < 5){
        alerta('The entered password is too short', e.target.parentElement);
        form[e.target.name] ='';
        return;
    }
    if(e.target.name === 'password' && e.target.value.lenght > 5){
        quitarAlerta(e.target.parentElement);
        return;
    } 


    e.target.classList.remove('failed');
    e.target.classList.add('succeed');
    quitarAlerta(e.target.parentElement);

    form[e.target.name] = e.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log(form);
}

function alerta(mensaje, referencia1){

    
    quitarAlerta(referencia1);
    const error = document.createElement('span');
    error.textContent = mensaje;
    error.classList.add('failed-span');

    referencia1.appendChild(error);
}

function quitarAlerta(referencia2){
    const alerta = referencia2.querySelector('.failed-span');
    // console.log(alerta);
     if(alerta){
         alerta.remove();
    }

}

function validarEmail(email){
    const regex = /^\w+([.-_+]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,10})+$/;
    const resultado = regex.test(email);
    return resultado;
}
```

```css
:root{
    --claro: #f8f8f8;
    /* --claro: #f6f4ff; */
    --claro-letra: #919191;
    --negro: #0a0a0a;
    /* --negro: #5f5db8; */
    /* --rojo-claro: #fff9f9; */
    /* --rojo: #de4647; */
    --morado: linear-gradient(45deg, #87adfe, #ff77cd);
    --azul: #6c7fde;
    --rojo-fondo: #f9e0e0;
    --rojo: #d32625;
    --verde-fondo: #e7f5ec;
    --verde: #65b987;

}
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.checkmark{
    color:var(--negro);
    /* transition: .2s; */
}
.filled{
    transition: .2s;
    color: var(--verde);
}

ion-icon {
    color:var(--negro);
    font-size: 24px !important;
}
.google, .apple{
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.google{
    font-size: 21px !important;
}


.theme{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    margin: 18px 35px 0px 0px
}
#moon{
    font-size: 18px !important;
    color: #e1ebfd;
    padding: 7px;
    /* background-color: rgb(129, 178, 246); */
    background-color:#6e92ff;
    border-radius: 80px;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
}

.sun{
    background-color: #ffdb6d !important;
    color: #9e7e3a !important;
    transition: .2s !important;
}
#moon:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

body{
    padding: 30px 0px 40px 0px;
}
header{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
}
div form{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
form #cabecera{
    display: grid;
    gap: 18px;
}

div a{
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-align: center;
}
.main{
    padding: 0 35px;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* display: grid;
    place-content: center; */
}

.head{
    display: grid;
    justify-items: start;
    gap: 10px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: var(--claro-letra);
}

.continue-with, .footer button{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: var(--claro);
    border: 2px solid var(--negro);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.continue-with:hover{
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.continue-with:focus{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid var(--azul);
}
.continue-with span, .footer button span{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--negro);
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 13px 0px;
}

.continue-with{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .1s;
}

h3{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}
h3::before,h3::after{
    background-color: var(--claro-letra);
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
h3:before{
    right: 0.5rem;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
h3:after{
    left: 0.5rem;
    margin-right: -50%;
}

label{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--negro);
}

input{
    padding: 13px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid var(--claro-letra);
    transition: .1s;
    background-color: var(--claro);
}
/* input::-moz-placeholder{
    opacity: 1;
} */
input[placeholder]{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 13px;
}

input:focus{
    border: 2px solid var(--azul);
    background-color: #fff;
}
/* input:hover{
    border: 2px solid var(--azul);
    background-color: #fff;
} */
input:focus-visible{
    outline: none;
}

.failed{
    background-color: var(--rojo-fondo);
    border: 2px solid var(--rojo);

}
.failed-span{
    /* background-color: var(--rojo-fondo); */
    color: var(--rojo);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: .2s;

}
.succeed{ 
    background-color: var(--verde-fondo);
    border: 2px solid var(--verde);
}

div p{
    font-weight: 500;
}
.agreed{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 18px 0 40px 0px;
    text-align: start;
    color: var(--negro);
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;

}
.footer{
    display: grid;
    gap: 18px;
}
.footer button{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-color: var(--negro);
    transition: .2s;
    cursor: auto;
    font-size: 17px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.footer button span{
    cursor:default;
}
.footer button:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.footer button span{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.footer p{
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer p a{
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--negro);
    transition: .2s;
}
.footer p a:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Main form styles */

.main-form div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}

.main-form{
    display: grid;
    /* grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); */
    row-gap: 18px;
    /* transition: .2s; */
    column-gap: 15px;
    /* margin-bottom: 40px; */

    grid-template-areas:
    "fn"
    "sn"
    "e"
    "p"
    ;
    
}

.main-form .input-name-1{
    grid-area: fn;
}
.main-form .input-name-2{
    grid-area: sn;
}
.main-form .input-email{
    grid-area: e;
}
.main-form .input-password{
    grid-area: p;
}


/* MediaQueries */

    @media screen and (min-width: 500px){
        .main-form{
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-areas:
            "fn sn"
            "e e"
            "p p"
            ;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 


    <div class="main">
        <div class="head">
            <!-- <header>Kove</header> -->
            <h1>Create an account</h1>
            <h2>Describe yourself as clearly so there are no mistakes.</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form id="formulario">
                <div id="cabecera">  
                    <a class="continue-with" href="#">
                        <ion-icon class="apple" name="logo-apple"></ion-icon>
                        <span>Continue with Apple</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="continue-with" href="#">
                        <ion-icon class="google" name="logo-google"></ion-icon>
                        <span>Continue with Google</span>
                    </a>
                </div>      
                <h3>or</h3>

                <div class="main-form">
                    <div class="input-name-1">
                        <input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="First name" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-name-2">
                        <input type="text" id="second-name" placeholder="Second name" name="secondName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-email">
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-password">
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="agreed"><ion-icon name="checkmark-circle-outline" class="checkmark"></ion-icon>Yes, I understand and agree to the Kove Terms of Service</button>
                
                <div class="footer">
                    <button disabled><span>Create Account</span></button>
                    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <span class="theme"><ion-icon name="moon" id="moon"></ion-icon></span>
    
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script src="icons.js"></script>
    <script src ="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.lenght` -> `.length` and remove the NOT in front of `!e.target.value.length < 5` if you want to NOT a relation operation, you use the opposite for `<` the opposite is `>=`. Also, you don't want to NOT that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, looks you have a typo,  You've written `lenght` instead of `length`.

Also you should remove `!` in the first condition because it negates the whole condition:

```
if(e.target.name === 'password' && e.target.value.length < 5){
    ...
}
```

Comment: "*because it negates the whole condition:*" it doesn't do that... it "negates" the property value. Which makes no real sense to do.